# I can't get Facebook user birthday

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have a user_birthday permission

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_birthday", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
```

and

```
NSString *birthday = user.birthday;
NSLog(@"BirthDay : %@",birthday);
```

but birthday is null

help me please

Comment: are you get [FBRequest requestForMe] for get user information?

Comment: No , i have - (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user

Comment: What API version are you using? With 2.4, the number of fields returned by default has been reduced, so you now have to specifically ask for additional fields. Go see their changelog for details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed your app by Facebook for "user_birthday" permission?

All the permissions except `public_profile`, `user_friends` and `email` should require, to get your app reviewed by Facebook first.

Check this link for more help-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review

Comment: I'm not ready to submit for reviewed , you have other way for get birthday?

Comment: It is not complusary that your app should be completed to submit review. You can submit your app.

Comment: where to submit??

Comment: submit to developer.facebbok.com - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review